# Backups (BackupAssist) are running more than the expected Time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, backup

What are the things need to checked if the backup jobs(BackupAssist) are running more than the expected Time.

Comment: It is important to provide context when asking a question on ServerFault. Please edit your question and provide some details. For example: How big are the backup jobs? Are these full backups, incremental backups, differential backups? What are you backing up? Has there been a change in disk usage on the volumes that you're backing up? Are you backing up across a LAN, across a WAN, to an external drive, or to tape? When was the last time that your backups ran within the expected time, and what has changed since then? Without details, your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. What is being backed up?  Files, system state, SQL, Exchange?
2. Has there been any change in the quantity of data?
3. Have there been any permissions changes that might cause the application to hang?
4. Are there any issues with the storage that is being backed up?  How about the storage you're backing up to?  RAID issues can cause slow reads, for example.
5. BackupAssist is perfectly willing to create filenames and paths that are longer than Windows supports, which it is then unable to delete.  (Especially if, like my predecessor, you decide to back up the Recycle Bin.)  Check for this as well.  You might be out of disk space on your backup volume.

BackupAssist has a console that will show you what's being backed up right now.  I suggest you look there first.

Comment: 1.)15GB of backup
2.)INcremental Backups
3.)APplication Database(MYSQL) Home & Network Share
4.)backing up across a LAN to a ISCSI mapped Locally and this Destination Disk doesn't have any issues.
5.)Since three days its performing slow
6.)NO changes in Permission
7.) has much more space in Destn Drive.

Comment: Can anyone Help me on this